# Shared class must not reference isolated class

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm adding a brand new entity that maps to an existing one:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(NewEntityPK.class)
public class NewEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID", nullable = false, length = 256)
    private String userId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "EXISTING_ENTITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "EXISTING_ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
    private ExistingEntity existingEntity;
}

@Entity
@Cacheable(true)
public class ExistingEntity implements Serializable {
}
```

Upon deployment I get:

> Exception [EclipseLink-195] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
> 2.1.3.v20110304-r9073): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
>  Exception
> Description: **The shared class com.example.model.NewEntity must not
> reference the isolated class com.example.model.ExistingEntity.**
> Mapping:
> org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[existingEntity]
> Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.example.model.NewEntity -->
> [DatabaseTable(NEW_ENTITY)])

I understand it's because `ExistingEntity` is annotated as not cacheable. Unfortunately, I cannot just enable cache because it cascades all around the entity graph, so I've been forced to disable caching for `NewEntity` too.

Is there an alternative that allows to keep `NewEntity` cached without touching other entities? I'll most likely only need to fetch one level of linked relationships starting on `NewEntity`, if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried using `@Cache(isolation = PROTECTED)`? Depending on whether you want `existingEntity` relationship to be cached alongside or not, you might also want `@Noncacheable` on top of `NewEntity.existingEntity`. You can read about the different type of caches [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/OTLCG/cache.htm#OTLCG94332). It might be outdated, but perhaps not; Eclipselink folks are notoriously bad at documenting their stuff, but hopefully it's better than nothing

Comment: @crizzis Apparently, the do-not-cache codebase-wide setting originates in a couple of read-only views that are updated by another system. My predecessors possibly got that same exception and did this as quick fix (I see no reason no avoid caching in the rest of entities). I'll check the docs you've linked and see if when I get back to code on Monday I can isolate those two other entities.

Comment: Better document more aimed at the JPA side of things that might help: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Shared_and_Isolated